# Is poor spelling/grammar a suitable reason to reject an edit in Documentation?

Tags: discussion, documentation, review-queues

I came across a proposed edit today to a topic which added an introduction where there wasn't one previously, but the quality of the written English was poor to the extent that it may not be readable or make sense to others.

Is this a valid reason to reject the edit (looking at the available rejection reasons, quality of spelling/grammar didn't seem to be an option), especially as it was not replacing or amending an existing introduction, but rather proposing one for the first time? Is something better than nothing, even if it might not be clear to some/many/most who read it?

What is the correct course of action when faced with a proposed edit like this?

Comment: Could you link to the edit in question?

Comment: Keep in mind that the goal is to have good documentation, not "any documentation". So poor grammar is not good enough. I'm not too familiar with documentation itself, can't you improve the edit to fix the language? On regular SO that would be the preferred path.

Comment: I don't appear to have the ability to re-edit myself, only accept or reject the proposed edit (perhaps with higher rep, I would be able to edit myself).

Comment: It depends. That's why we have reviewers. What do you think should happen?

Comment: I think what has been proposed could easily be rephrased into valid/correct English and it would read better and be more useful then. My problem is I don't know how to make this happen as I only have the option to accept or reject - I do not have enough rep in the tag in question to contribute myself it seems.

Comment: @3N1GM4 As far as I have seen, no one can "reject and edit" or "improve" for Proposed Changes in Documentation. You'll instead need to wait for the outcome of the review, then edit from there. If it's rejected and you view the link to the change, you should see a "Improve Draft" button on the review page. You can use that to update it. If the change is accepted, just go and edit the example(s) is was on.

Comment: @WaiHaLee unfortunately the edit in question is no longer in the review queue and it was rejected (as the topic has not changed), so I cannot provide a link.

Comment: You can still provide a link. If you go to the tag's dashboard, you can go to the changes at the bottom of the page, click the rejected tab, and click on the review from there. (This is also how you can get to the "Improve Draft" button I mentioned.)

Comment: Ah, I now also see that I can add a comment to advise the editor on how they could improve their edit, which someone else has already done, so it should be possible to resolve that way. Thanks all!

Comment: You think adding poorly-written content is bad? You haven't seen edits that *change* correct spelling and grammar to *incorrect* spelling and grammar.

Comment: @CodyGray yes, I did find that question before I posted, but didn't appreciate at the time that it was effectively the same question.

Comment: I really wish there was some way to get people to stop interpreting the auto-generated "possible duplicate" comments as implying a subtext of "you damn idiot, why didn't you find this one already?" I didn't mean it that way. There are a lot of questions on Meta; you don't have to apologize for asking a reasonable, well-asked question that just happens to have already been discussed once before. This question was so reasonable I even upvoted it. The reason these comments are left is to give you a chance to edit in clarification if you are confident it's *not* a duplicate before it gets closed.

Comment: @CodyGray I didn't I interpret your comment that way, so no need to feel frustrated. The tone of my reply was meant to be thankful rather than anything else, sorry if it came across differently. Thanks for the up vote.